# javascript - timeout function if not on url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a news feed script that retrieves new items from the database and informs the user every now and again. Problem is I also have a history api script so if the user navigates away from the Home page (where the news feed is) the function is still carried out, problem for my server. So, I thought i'd set the interval as a handler and clear it when the page url is not for the home page.

```
var currentUrl = $(location).attr('pathname');
var url = currentUrl.replace('/', '');
var handle=self.setInterval(function(){newsCheck()},1000); //set up interval handler for cancellation when not on home page

if (url != 'Home' ){ //timeout newsCheck
       handle = window.clearInterval(handle);
}
```

This however, does not work as the interval is never cleared. Oh I should say it runs on DOM ready, might be something to do with it.

I am thinking that because of the history api script does not re run this news feed script each time that the `url` variable remains unchanged and the function is continued. The obvious way around it would be to put the `clearInterval` in the history api script but then ofcourse the variables and function is not there.

I neeed to get around this but;

**1.** I don't want to run anymore ajax requests, theres enough of them already.

**2.**The solution must be light as if not i may as well just leave it running silently in the background.

Comment: When you say that it 'does not work', do you mean the interval never gets cleared?

Comment: Why use `$(location).attr('pathname')` instead of `location.pathname`? That's using jQuery for the sake of using jQuery.

Comment: Yes sorry, that was a poor way of putting it.

Comment: move your `currentUrl` and `url` variables inside the handler and if it's not home, just return.  Keep the interval alive and just exit the handler early.

Comment: @JanDvorak fair comment, thanks.